# C# DiffSharp v0.7.7 Looking for FSharp.Core v4.4.0.0

Tags: c#, f#, diffsharp

I've been trying to use the most recent version of DiffSharp (v0.7.7) with C#. I keep getting the following error:

> Error 3   Assembly 'DiffSharp, Version=0.7.7.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

It seems to be looking for FSharp.Core Version 4.4.0.0. As far as I'm aware - no such thing exists. Or am I wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10 and have updated absolutely everything I could think of. My .Net build is 4.6.1.

I tried doing this fix also mentioned in Stack Overflow: [Could not load file or assembly FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0 Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801302/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-fsharp-core-version-4-0-0-0-azure-web-role)

but it didn't yield anything.

Has anyone had similar experiences like this?

Any thoughts/ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course FSharp.Core Version 4.4.0.0 exists. Why would you assume it doesn't, especially being two versions behind on Visual Studio?

Comment: So which version of Visual Studio does it exist on? Might have to upgrade...

Comment: Latest version of FSharp.Core is 4.4.0.1 I believe. You can get the nuget package for it and/or set binding redirect. Or try using a lower version of .Net. Yes, VS2012 is F#3.0 which is 4.3.0.0.

Comment: See [FSharp.Core version numbers](https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html#fsharpcore-version-numbers).

Comment: VS2015 update 2 or 3 with FSharp Power Tools should make your life easier :)

Comment: I so far have seen only one other diffsharp user on SO so maybe he can chime in.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - will look into this. I think I can access the above versions to at least see if it works. And yes, if there's anyone who has used diffsharp and knows something their input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to the same problem with diffSharp and C#.
I solved issue by adding the FSharep.core nuget packet to project.
*Install-Package FSharp.Core -Version 4.7.0*

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no explanation for why the FSharp.Core version 4.4.0 package is no longer available, I have found that the later 4.5.0 package (which is available as of Jan 2021) worked for me.