# .NET FileLoadException with FSharp.Core version "4.3.1.0"

Tags: .net, f#

I was developing some new unit tests with the NUnit framework. Some were passing until I've hit the dreaded exception for F# users. I've made sure to add the bindingRedirect node in my packages.config file but it's not working.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                              culture="neutral"/>
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
                <packages>
                  <package id="Akka" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="Akka.FSharp" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="Akka.TestKit" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="Akka.TestKit.NUnit" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="FsPickler" version="1.2.21" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="FSPowerPack.Core.Community" version="3.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="FSPowerPack.Linq.Community" version="3.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="NUnit" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
                  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.1.36" targetFramework="net461" />
             </packages>
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Looking at those links down below didn't help me fix my issue.

1. [FSharp.Core: Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206991/fsharp-core-could-not-load-file-or-assembly)
2. [Could not load file or assembly FSharp.Core, Version=4.0.0.0 Azure Web Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801302/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-fsharp-core-version-4-0-0-0-azure-web-role)
3. [.NET runtime tries to load FSharp.Core 4.3.0 even if all projects reference 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541058/net-runtime-tries-to-load-fsharp-core-4-3-0-even-if-all-projects-reference-4-3)

Comment: You did add to **app**.config, not packages.config, right?

Comment: It's a library project since I'm only doing unit tests. I don't have a app.config

Comment: Try adding the redirects to your test projects app.config (create it if it doesn't exist)

Comment: Would I be better to re-create that project and this time, use a Console App for my unit tests ? '

Comment: no, a library (dll) project is fine. Just create the app.config and add the redirects there.